# Boostrap modal element offset giving zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

To scroll to an element in my Bootstrap modal, I can check the offset of the element. There are for instance 8 div's, each with their own id (#row-1, #row-2, etc.). If I open the modal and then input the following into the console, I get the correct offset value.

```
$('#row-6').offset()['top'];
```

But when I `console.log` this into the code itself, after opening the modal with `.modal('show')`, I get `0` back.

How can this difference occur? I tried all the solutions I could find on here, but all solutions gave me the same `0`.

My problem would also be solved if I could scroll to the element in any other way with JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must wait for the modal to be shown:

```
  // The modal is shown
    $('#yourModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      // Get the right offset
      var offset = $("#yourelement").offset();
      var offsetTop = offset.top;
      var offsetLeft = offset.left;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, almost two years after asking this question it has been answered!

Comment: Thanks I was using position, which was 15,15... offset works.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the elements are not done being shown yet in order to give you the correct value? Try using a setTimeout to verify this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('#row-6').offset()['top']; }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> My problem would also be solved if I could scroll to the element in
>   any other way with javascript.

So, here is my suggestion to your problem:

html:

```
<button id="modal_show" class="btn btn-warning">Show modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal modal-flex fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top:60px;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" style="padding:5px;">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row" id="row1">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <p>
                            This is row 1
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" id="row2">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <p>
                            This is row 2
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" id="row3">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <p>
                            This is row 3
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" id="row4">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <p>
                            This is row 4
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" id="row5">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <p>
                            This is row 5
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" id="row6">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <p>
                            This is row 6
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" id="row7">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <p>
                            This is row 7
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <p class="pull-right">
                            <span class="scroller" data-to="3">Go To 3</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" id="row8">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <p>
                            This is row 8
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <p class="pull-right">
                            <span class="scroller" data-to="2">Go To 2</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 pull-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content --> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog --> 
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#modal_show').on('click', function(){
    $('#myModal').modal({show: true});
});

$('.scroller').click(function(){
    var targetId = $(this).attr("data-to");
    $('#myModal').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#row"+targetId).position().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

and some css:

```
.row {
    min-height:100px;
}
.scroller {
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

When you scroll down to div's 7 and 8, you will notice links that scroll you up to div #3 and #2 respectively.

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xL9at8sc/

Hope that helps you and others...